# Assigning an ID to a ViewBag and giving it a value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, viewbag

I currently have a controller that cycles through my "Sites" database and gets a value based on their site ID
It looks like this

```
 osiTotal[s.ID] = osiPartCost[s.ID] + osiCompCost[s.ID] + osiItemCost[s.ID];                 
 ViewBag.OSITotal[s.ID] = osiTotal[s.ID]; // Receive error message on this line
```

And then my View looks like this

```
 @foreach (Site s in sites)
{
 <tr>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">Total</td>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">@ViewBag.OSITotal[s.ID]</td>
 </tr>
}
```

But I receive the error

**Cannot perform runtime binding to null reference**

I have tried doing this to my view

```
 @foreach (Site s in sites)
{
 <tr>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">Total</td>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">@ViewBag.OSITotal[1]</td>
 </tr>
}
```

Where I automatically assign the `@ViewBag.OSITotal` a value of "1"
But still receive the same error

So I am the issue has to be when I'm trying to assign the value of osiTotal[s.ID] to the ViewBag

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of ViewBag.OSITotal?  You need to create and assign a new array or collection to it first, or it will be null.  ViewBag.OSITotal[0] tries to dereference a null collection giving the error.  For example, if ID is an int:

```
ViewBag.OSITotal = new Dictionary<int,int>();
```

Comment: The type of it is float

Comment: Now in my view I receive the error at the ViewBag saying 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'